# How do I know the limit for the calculation of normalized wave function.

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let we have a eigen function  for dumbbell ball given which is $ \phi= A e^{i x}$ and I have to determine  the normalization constant A. I know in thios case I will have to write

$$\int \phi \phi^* dx  $$.  Now how do i know the limit of the integration?

Comment: It's the entire coordinate space. In practice wave functions are falling off exponentially in most cases, so a relatively small integration volume would give you a good enough result for all practical purposes, but working with such cutoffs makes really no sense for single particle theory. The complication you are up against is that for free waves the normalization is not done trough a finite normalization constant but with a Dirac delta function, which is really a distribution aka generalized function. The mathematicians are dealing with these properly as "measures", I believe.

Comment: In a gre question (http://grephysics.net/ans/8677/28) I can see a similar example where they have used the limit as 0 to $2\pi$ but i see no mentioning the limit. So how they guess this?

Comment: Integration between $0$ and $2\pi$ is only valid for cyclical coordinates, i.e. angles. For spatial coordinates you have to integrate over the entire space.

Comment: Can you provide me a list of  limit for different object shapes?

Comment: The limit is always the same: the entire range of the variables.

Comment: If it's a dumbbell (rigid rotor), then the integration limits would be $0$ to $2\pi$. Or, if you choose x to be the arclength distance along a circle, then the limits would be $0$ to $L$ where $L$ is the dumbbell's circumference. If integration were over all $x$, then the integral would diverge.